# Similar questions within a few minutes. Could this be malicious?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I was following the [java] tag and noticed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1880842/marwa-roshan?tab=questions&sort=newest) user.

He asked these questions within a few minutes:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14802900/java-program-to-scan-for-specific-letters-in-a-word
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14803169/in-java-i-need-to-make-a-program-that-scans-words-for-certain-letters-
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14803414/i-need-to-write-a-java-program-that-compares-two-strings

All of them are very similar, and the user has not voted, commented or accepted any of the answers he got.

Could this behavior be considered malicious? Should I flag for moderator attention?

Comment: I don't see anything *malicious* - aside from being just another help vampire.

Comment: @Mystical That could be seen as either malicious or just annoying.  Some people tend to view help vampires as malicious, though.

Comment: It looks as if they are posting an absracted version of homework questions or something.

Comment: @AlexHopeO'Connor but it is all from the same user.

Comment: @user000001, yeah that was my point, the questions are similar but different like you would find in a homework excersise with the purpose of teaching Java string manipulation etc

Comment: IMHO this behavior should be bannable.

Comment: @user000001 It is. It's called the "Question Ban".